# Set proxy to docker selenium node/chrome

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I try to use selenium hub/nodes as docker containers like here [selenium/node-chrome][1]. 
Also I have proxy-manager at 127.0.0.1:24000.
Question is: how to launch chrome node so, that traffic from that node will go through my proxy?

I tried to pass `--proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1:24000` as chrome options argument when creating web driver, but I suppose chrome tries to use that host/port inside docker, not my system's.

I'm not an experienced docker user, so please try to explain as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to connect from docker container to port, which is exposed on the host machine.

I would recommend wrapping proxy-manager into docker container too, for consistency.

But if you don't want to do it, then you can take a look at [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

It will help you to use host machine port at your chrome docker container.